# Google Adwords API: Get criterion info on APIError

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-ads-api

Is there a way to get the criterion info from an APIError?

```
    MutateJobService mutateJobService = (MutateJobService)user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201309.MutateJobService);
    JobResult jobResult = mutateJobService.getResult(new BulkMutateJobSelector { includeStats = true, jobIds = jobIDs }); 
    SimpleMutateResult results = (SimpleMutateResult)jobResult.Item;

    if (results.errors != null)
    {
        foreach (ApiError apiError in results.errors)
        {
            // get criterion info
        }
    }
```

I'm finding it difficult to get detailed info on a specific error (which is obviously important to have for logging purposes). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can expect the error and look at its

- `fieldPath`
- `trigger`
- `errorString`
- `type`
- `reason`

More documentation here: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/latest/CampaignService.ApiError

Comment: Correct... I know I can access the direct properties of the error, however I'm looking for a way to dig deeper and access the actual criterion information. There's gotta be a way...

Comment: You do also get `results`, which is the list of operands you've submitted - criteria in your case - doesnt' that help?

Comment: No, since if a specific criteria failed, the operand.Item evaluates to a "PlaceHolder" and cannot be casted to the correct CriterionType to get the property values.

Comment: You have to save the original operations array. The trigger should contain a string that includes the index of the operation that failed.

Comment: @JeremyAube Thanks. Wow, I guess if that's the only way... I have no choice.